# Singular values inequality.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

$\def\abs#1{\lvert#1\rvert}\def\Abs#1{\lVert#1\rVert}$
Let $\sigma_1$ be the largest singular value of $A\in M_{m,n}.$ Show that
$$
\sigma_1(A)=\max\{\abs{x^*Ay}:\text{$x\in {\mathbb{C}^m}$, $y \in {\mathbb{C}^n}$ are unit vectors}\}.
$$

I know that 
$$
\abs{x^*Ay}\leq\Abs x_2\Abs{A y}_2\leq \Abs x_2\Abs y_2 \sigma_1(A),
$$
but I don't know that how to find vectors $x$ and $y$ for which this inequality is an equality.

Answer (score 0):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value), a singular value $\lambda$ of $A$ is an eigenvalue of $A^*A$, say with eigenvector $v$.  Now let $x$ and $y$ be scalings of $A v$ and $v$, respectively.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your point.Can you please make it more clear? I was thinking  to use singular value decomposition.

Comment: You are asking how to find $x$ and $y$ to obtain an inequality.  This answer uses the definition of a singular value to give you $x$ and $y$ (unless $\sigma_1(A) = 0$, in which case it is a triviality).

Comment: I want to find x and yto obtain an equality.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, I meant 'equality', even though I wrote 'inequality'.  This answer gives $x$ and $y$ that produce equality.